# Add automatic git merge step in VSTS CI

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, branching-and-merging, pull-request, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to merge my *dmz* branch to *master* branch when test passed. I cannot find a merge step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don’t want to use Pull Request, you can call git command to merge and push to maser branch during build.

1. Add Command line task below to test task
2. Tool: git; Arguments: push origin HEAD:master; Working folder: $(build.sourcesdirectory)

Answer (score 3):

As DMZ flow mentioned, you should use **pull request** to merge `dmz` branch into `master`. In order the merge and build can be execute automatically, you can use [**web hooks**](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/marketplace/integrate/service-hooks/services/webhooks).

> In order to preserve the pristine and reliable nature of master, we're
>   going to impose some constraints. No one can ever put code directly
>   into master. Everyone has to work on feature branches, and those
>   feature branches can only be brought into master by way of the pull
>   request. Pull requests will be built automatically and their build
>   status checked before merge into master, thus ensuring that code
>   coming into master has always a) passed automated checks like
>   compilation and testing, and b) passed code review. Pull requests
>   should be used for everything, from tiny whitespace changes to
>   sweeping refactorings. A healthy team opens many, many pull requests
>   every day.

The flow should be: create a pull request to merge `dmz` into `master` -> build `dmz` branch automatically (trigger by web hook) -> if the build is successful (detect by another web hook) ->merge `dmz` into `master` and queue build on `master` branch.

Prerequisite:

- Two web hooks to detect pull request create and build success on `dmz` branch.
- Two build definition to build `dmz` and `master` branch separately.
- A website you develop by your request to receive message after `dmz` build successful, then merge `dmz` into `master` and queue another build on `master` branch.

**Web hook to detect  pull request created:** in a VSTS project web page -> Services Hooks -> create subscription -> Web Hooks -> Next -> select pull request merge commit created to trigger event -> select your repo -> select `master` as target branch -> Next -> URL for your website -> finish.

**Web hook to detect build successful** on `dmz` branch -> create the other web hook -> select build completed to trigger this event -> select the build definition for build `dmz` branch -> select succeeded as build status -> Next -> use your website URL to receive the message.

**Website functions should include:**

- Receive message from dmz branch build success
- Then [complete pull request](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#update-a-pull-request) to merge `dmz` branch `into master` and [queue build for `master` branch](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#queue-a-build).